# selenium js webdriver - attach to active session

Tags: javascript, session, selenium

I am using Node.js with `selenium-webdriver` package to run my tests.
every time a test start, the web driver starts a new session and open a new window.
I am trying to get the session Id and use it later using `getSession()` 
([doc referance link](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/source/lib/webdriver/builder.js.src.html) )

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var SeleniumServer = require('selenium-webdriver/remote').SeleniumServer;

var server = new SeleniumServer('./seleniumServer/selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar', {
    port: 4444
});
server.start();

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .usingServer(server.address())
        .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.firefox())
        .build();

console.log(driver.getSession());
```

But this causes an exception:

```
getSession();
^
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getSession'
    at Object.<anonymous> (\testing\demo_1.js:14:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with it and how I get and set the selenium session id?
Most importantly, how do I use the `sessionId` for attaching to an opened browser session?

Answer (score 5):

If your webdriver building procedure was successful, `driver` should have method `getSession()`. The documentation of getSession() can be found [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_ThenableWebDriver.html#getSession).

However, what is returned by `getSession()`is a promise, so you won't get the session id directly from the return value. You need to do this:

```
 driver.getSession()
                .then( function(session){
                    var session_id = session.getId();
                });
```

Very likely you need to save the session id in a file, and then when running the program next time, attach to this session id using this function:

```
browser = webdriver.WebDriver.attachToSession(...);
```

, of which documentation can be found [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_WebDriver.html#WebDriver.attachToSession).

**However,** the problem is that the above function call `attachToSession()` does not notify you whether it has succeeded. The way I worked around it is to call `browser.getTitle()` using the returned WebDriver object, and wait for it to resolve/reject. And we will know whether we have successfully attached to the session id.

---

**Set up webdriver:**

In response to user3789620 's question, I put the code for setting up webdriver here:

```
var webdriver_server = 'http://localhost:9515', // chromedriver.exe serves at this port 
chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome'),
options = new chrome.Options(),
webdriver = require( 'selenium-webdriver'),
Http = require( 'selenium-webdriver/http');
options.setChromeBinaryPath(your_chrome_binary_path);

var browser = new webdriver.Builder()
  .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
  .setChromeOptions(options)
  .usingServer(webdriver_server)
  .build()

if( 'undefined' != typeof saved_session_id && saved_session_id!= ""){
  console.log("Going to attach to existing session  of id: " + saved_session_id);
  client = new Http.HttpClient( webdriver_server );
  executor = new Http.Executor( client);
  browser = webdriver.WebDriver.attachToSession( executor, saved_session_id);
}
```

Comment: getting the sessionID is easy but how do I attach to it? I am using the syntax from the examples to create a driver with
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();

How do I attach to my previous sessions' Id now?

Comment: @user3789620 You need to setup webdriver correctly. I've added some codes to the end of my original answer. Please try and see if it works.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to [gm2008](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2197555/gm2008), whose [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42232123/5072076) got me on the right track. The `attachToSession` function was showing up as `undefined` for me which may have been an implementation change (I am using `4.0.0-alpha.1` of `selenium-webdriver`). However, I was able to accomplish the desired behavior with the following in TypeScript:

```
import wd, { WebDriver, Session } from 'selenium-webdriver'
import { HttpClient, Executor } from 'selenium-webdriver/http'

// My server URL comes from running selenium-standalone on my machine
const server: string = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'

async function newBrowserSessionId(): Promise<string> {
  const browser: WebDriver = new wd.Builder()
    .withCapabilities(wd.Capabilities.chrome())
    .usingServer(server)
    .build()

  const session: Session = await browser.getSession()

  return session.getId()
}

async function getExistingBrowser(sessionId: string): Promise<WebDriver> {
  const client: HttpClient = new HttpClient(server)
  const executor: Executor = new Executor(client)
  const session: Session = new Session(sessionId, wd.Capabilities.chrome())

  return new WebDriver(session, executor)
}

async function driveExistingBrowser(browser: WebDriver): Promise<void> {
  await browser.get('https://www.google.com/')
}

async function closeExistingBrowser(browser: WebDriver): Promise<void> {
  await browser.close()
}

async function connectAndDrive(): Promise<void> {
  const sessionId: string = await newBrowserSessionId()
  const existingBrowser: WebDriver = await getExistingBrowser(sessionId)

  await driveExistingBrowser(existingBrowser)
  await closeExistingBrowser(existingBrowser)
}

connectAndDrive()
```

As long as you keep the session open and have a way of passing the ID around, you can attach to the existing `Session` even after your script that initiates it has completed executing. The `closeExistingBrowser()` function can be used whenever you are ready to perform cleanup.

Comment: Can you help me to make that code in nodejs and not typescript?

Comment: I got a problem in:  error TypeError: wd.Webdriver is not a constructor

Comment: @motis10 You would just need to remove the type annotations to make it regular JS.  Where are you calling wd.Webdriver? Is it supposed to be wd.WebDriver (with the D capitalized)?

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking into cookies to persist your sessions. [webdriver.WebDriver.Options docs should help](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebDriver_Options.html#webdriver.WebDriver.Options.Cookie). One way to achieve this is to save the cookies to an external file before you quit the session and load the cookies from this external file every time you starts test.

Comment: The OP is not talking about the browser's session but Selenium's session.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `attachToSession()` like so:

```
webdriver.attachToSession(sessionId);
```

Also see [the docs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebDriver.html#WebDriver.attachToSession) for more info.